# Control.Exception.evaluate treats thunks generated by equivalent functions differently

Tags: haskell

Here are two equivalent partial functions:

- `\True -> \() -> ()`
- `\True () -> ()`

Applying either to `False` should raise a `PatternMatchFail` exception.

When I use `Control.Exception.evaluate` to force a thunk made from the former to WHNF, it forces the `PatternMatchFail` exception:

```
ghci> _ <- evaluate $ (\True -> \() -> ()) False
*** Exception: <interactive>:10:18-35: Non-exhaustive patterns in lambda
```

When I use the latter form, it doesn't:

```
ghci> _ <- evaluate $ (\True () -> ()) False
```

Why not?

(on GHC-8.0.1)

Comment: Hunh. Looking at the core it seems like the compiler switches the argument order for `\True () -> ()` into `\() -> \True -> ()`

Comment: In ghci, an easy way of forcing thunks is ``ghci> my_thunk `seq` ()``; it doesn't require an extra import.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the Haskell 2010 report:

> The following identity holds:
>
> ```
> \ p1 … pn -> e    =   \ x1 … xn -> case (x1, …, xn) of (p1, …, pn) -> e
> ```
>
> https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-260003.3

So `\True () -> e` desugars to `\x y -> case (x, y) of (True, ()) -> e`, which after partial application to `False` is `\y -> case (False, y) of ...` i.e., a function abstraction, so that's not bottom.

In contrast, `\True -> f` (where `f = \() -> e`) desugars to `\x -> case x of True -> ...`, and there's the exception.